# File new line writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io

```
from re import findall
output = 0

f = open("100$ School.txt", "w+")

f.write(str(output))
```

My goal is to have it so every time it runs it writes it in a new line.
Thank you to anyone who takes to the time to awnser

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to append for it to not overwrite. so `w+` needs to be `a+`

```py
from re import findall
output = 0

f = open("100$ School.txt", "a+")

f.write(str(output)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
with open("100$ School.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(str(output)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
f = open("100$ School.txt", "a+") # "a+" for append
f.write(f"{output}\n")
```